# Scrapy - how to index and extract from html tables

Tags: html, xpath, scrapy

This is the webpage I am scraping: http://laxreports.sportlogiq.com/nll/GS2200.html

Below is the code for the spider I created:

```
import scrapy    

class MatchesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'matches'
    allowed_domains = ['laxreports.sportlogiq.com']
    start_urls = ['http://laxreports.sportlogiq.com/nll/GS2200.html']

    def parse(self, response):
        tables = response.xpath('//table')
        print(tables)
        table = tables[0].xpath('//tbody')
```

I see 22 tables that have been selected for this XPath expression but my problem is that I don't fully understand how to select each individual table and extract its contents.

I am a beginner in scrapy and after searching online for a solution all I see is how to select the tables using the class or ID which in this case is not an option.

Comment: Cannot view your site. It says access denied.

Comment: I removed the trailing slash after the url, now you can view the page. Or try going to https://www.nll.com/schedule/scores/ and hover over one of the matches you should see a button labelled Game Recap appear.  Click on it to see the page I am talking about.

Comment: Do you mean you want all the tables? Why do you not simply loop over them then?

Comment: I am a beginner in this, I am not sure how to loop over them all.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using only pandas

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

dfs = pd.read_html('https://laxreports.sportlogiq.com/nll/GS2200.html')
df = dfs[10]#.to_csv('d.csv', index = False)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
  0              1  2   3    4    5   6     7   8   9   10    11     12
0     #           Name  G   A  +/-  PIM   S  SOFF  LB   T  CT    FO    TOF
1     2       W.Malcom  0   0    0    0   1     1   1   4   0     -  11:28
2     3      T.Edwards  0   0   -2    2   0     0   8   1   2  7-18  20:28
3     4     J.Sullivan  0   0   -3    2   0     0   3   0   0     -  15:29
4    11       T.Stuart  0   0   -3    0   0     0   4   1   1     -  21:09
5    14      W.Jeffrey  0   1   -1    0   0     0   9   2   1     -  19:17
6    16          R.Lee  2   1    2    0   9     4   6   6   1     -  23:13
7    17       C.Wardle  2   0    1    2   5     3   4   2   2     -  20:55
8    18    R.Hope  (A)  0   0   -2    2   0     0  11   0   0     -  22:02
9    20        J.Ruest  3   2    3    0   8     1   3   2   0     -  24:16
10   23       J.Gilles  0   0   -1    0   0     0   4   0   3     -  14:44
11   27     S.Carnegie  0   0   -1    0   0     0   3   0   0     -  12:19
12   37  D.Coates  (C)  0   0    0    0   1     0   1   0   0   1-1   2:31
13   51   E.McLaughlin  0   5    2    0   7     3   5   7   0     -  21:41
14   55      D.Kinnear  0   1    2    0   2     0   2   1   0   0-2  10:14
15   67       K.Killen  1   1    0    0   6     1   4   2   0     -  16:42
16   82  J.Cupido  (A)  0   1   -1    0   3     0   4   1   0     -  20:52
17   86        J.Lintz  0   1   -1    0   0     0   4   0   1     -  19:26
18   30      T.Carlson  0   0  NaN    0   0     0   0   0   0     -    NaN
19   45         D.Ward  0   0  NaN    0   0     0   0   1   0     -    NaN
20  NaN        Totals:  8  13  NaN    8  42    13  76  30  11  8-21    NaN
```

Comment: A really easy and great way you suggested. For someone who wants to read more about the method he used:
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html